# Database reference not been recognised

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a for loop that is creating seats. I am trying to check if the seat was already registered(booked) in our database, so as I initiate the seat I want to get into my database and check if its already there, so I put in a method called look within the two for loops, like this

```
for (i = 0; i < maxRow; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < maxColumn; j++) {
            final SeatMo seat = new SeatMo();
            seat.row = i;
            seat.column = j;
            seat.status = 1;
            look(seat,i,j)
            seatTable[i][j] = seat;
        }
    }
```

The method look is where the reference is, when I saved the seat in the database, I named the child by the specific seat that was selected e.g col:2 row:3, here is the look method

```
  private void look(final SeatMo seat, final int a, final int b) {
    databaseRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("col:" + i + " row:" + j)) {
                seat.status = 0;
            } else {
                    seat.status = 1;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
      });
    }
```

In my mind I want it to check for every seat as the seat is being initiated, but for some reason which I hope you may find in the code about, when the method look is called, it skips the reference(databaseRef completely). My question is, what could be causing the reference to be skipped and how can I make sure it does not get skipped?

The databaseRef is declared in the Oncreate method, it is a field

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_seats);

    if(getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }

    currUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    Intent callingIntent = getIntent();
    maxC = Integer.valueOf(callingIntent.getStringExtra("col"));
    maxR = Integer.valueOf(callingIntent.getStringExtra("row"));
    decks = Integer.valueOf(callingIntent.getStringExtra("deck"));
    fare = Double.valueOf(callingIntent.getStringExtra("fare"));
    driver = callingIntent.getStringExtra("id");
    destination = callingIntent.getStringExtra("dest");





    databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("coach-drivers" + "/" + driver + "/" + "clients" );


    initSeatTable(maxC,maxR);
    selectedSeats = new ArrayList<>();
    mMovieSeatView1= (MovieSeatView) findViewById(R.id.seat_view_one);
    deck = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.top_bottom);
    mMovieSeatView1.setSeatTable(seatTable);
    mMovieSeatView1.setPresenter(this);



  }
```

The ref has the right route

Have tried changing the route to the ref like this

```
   databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("coach-drivers").child(driver).child("clients");
```

still does not get to the onDataChange() and onCancel method

This is the Json structure of my database

```
  {
"coach-drivers": {
    "iiiiiiiiiiiiiii": {
        "clients": {
            "col:3 row:2": "one",
            "col:3 row:1:"one",
             "col:1 row:3" : "one"
            }
        }
    }

 }
```

the iiiiiiiiiii is for the driverId, represented by driver field initiated in OnCreate method

SOLVED BY USING CLOUD FIRESTORE, STILL DON'T KNOW WHY FIREBASE REFERENCE WAS BEING SKIPPED THOUGH

Comment: Sir, where is your databaseRef ?

Comment: It is in the OnCreate Method, its a field

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, move the logic of checking if the seat was already registered inside `onDataChange()` method. You cannot simply use `seat.status` outside that method because the value will be always `null` due the asynchronous behaviour of the method.

Having all the logic inside that method, will solve the issue. If want to use the value outside, please see my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44152775/how-to-get-value-async-in-outside-method-ondatachange).

Comment: just tried it, didn't work, still skips the reference leading to the app crashing

Comment: seatTable is now null, because the reference was skipped, so the table was never initiated

Comment: Define `seatTable` also inside `onDataChange()` method. Does it work?

Comment: yes I did, the problem is, when the program is running is does not even get to the onDataChange() method, it gets  
       databaseRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()  het and skips everything

Comment: by everything, I mean every in the onDataChange() method, and onCancelled method,

Comment: Change this line of code: `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("coach-drivers" + "/" + driver + "/" + "clients" );` with `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("coach-drivers").child(driver).child("clients");`

Answer (score 0):

Put your reference inside your look method

Also keep `seatTable[i][j] = seat` in OnDataChange as show below:

```
private void look(final SeatMo seat, final int a, final int b) {

    databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("coach-drivers" + "/" + driver + "/" + "clients" );
    databaseRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("col:" + i + " row:" + j)) {
                    seat.status = 0;
                } else {
                    seat.status = 1;
                }
                 seatTable[i][j] = seat;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
      });


    }
```

Comment: The issue is with your for loop.

Comment: I have my answer please check it. Try this. I am not sure but this can help

Comment: Can you please provide your json structure in firebase database so that I can apply some other logic.

Comment: the answer that came before this one, suggested I initiate the table in onDatachange() method, I did that and still the reference is being skipped,

Comment: Your issue is with Loop

Comment: OK let me clear your question You are using this look method and looping it to show which seats have been already booked so user should know about booked seats . Right ? 0 means its booked and 1 means its not . and your loop is not calling firebase and showing all seats status 1 means available ?